# Angular 4 regex to check if string contains atleast 4 alphabetic characters

Tags: regex, angular

I am validating password field to check if contains at least 4 alphabetic characters. Following regex I have used:

```
[a-zA-Z]{4,}
```

The problem is that the above regex works if all 4 alphabetic characters are consecutive.

Input:

```
ab1cde
```

Expected output:

```
true
```

Actual output with above the regex: `null`

Answer (score 1):

You should include non-alphabetic characters too:

```
^(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){4}
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jCehq4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead here

```
^(?=(?:.*[A-Za-z]){4})
```

[**`regex demo`**](https://regex101.com/r/rWZy7e/1/)

Lookahead is of zero width. So it doesn't consumes any string i.e. position of checking doesn't change.